# Is it possible to prevent a class from using a method in java?

Tags: java, methods

Suppose I have a class called `Foo`. This class will be modified by many people, and WILL print information to the console. To this effect, we have the following method:

```
private void print(String message){ ... }
```

which prints out to the screen in the format we want.

However, while reviewing code from other devs I see that they constantly call `System.out.println(...)`
instead, which results in barely-readable printouts.

My question is the following: is it possible to prevent any and every use of System.out.println() in `Foo.java`? If so, how?

I've tried looking this up, but all I found had to do with inheritance, which is not related to my question.

Thanks a lot!
N.S.

EDIT: I know that whatever I have to do to prevent the use of a method could be removed by a dev, but we have as a policy never to remove code marked `//IMPORTANT` so it could still be used as a deterrent.

EDIT2: I know I can simply tell the devs not to do it or use code reviews to filter the "errors" out but 1) I'm already doing it and it costs a lot of time and 2) the question is whether this is possible or not, NOT how to deal with my devs.

Comment: How about implementing this with process/communication rather than code - e.g. tell the devs "Don't use sysout?"

Comment: tell the programmers you will cut their salary if they do.

Comment: Use a logging library like `log4j` instead of printing to the console directly. Configuring what gets logged where is what they're for. Beat developers with an increasingly heftier stick until they switch.

Comment: The best thing to address this issue is a tool for measuring the coding standard compliance.

Comment: I think one way may be use PMD or some code review tool with rule which errors System.out, no check-in if there is PMD error for System.out.

Comment: I like your solutions, but 1) I can't cut salaries and 2) I've tried to tell them multiple times, and it never works. Even if they did, I'm now curious to know whether this is possible or not.

Comment: @vulkanino If I was threatened with a salary cut over something like this I'd quit on the spot. (That said I also probably wouldn't be stubborn over being asked to replace `println()` with `debug()`.)

Comment: If you can't prevent people editing the code and adding println statements, how are you going to prevent them from editing whatever code you end up coming with to do it anyways? Or still not using your print statement but some other roundabout way? It sounds like you are having a communication problem not a code problem.

Comment: @onit if they're using sysouts they probably won't figure out too much ;)

Comment: @inerdial Wait you'd be actually angry if someone threatened with  repercussion because you didn't follow the documentation and wrote unusable code? (same goes with style guides - I may not like all of them, but I certainly still follow them when working on a larger project, everything else just doesn't work) I'd expect repeating offenders to be fired - what do I want with programmers who are incapable of reading documentation and writing useful code even after several remarks? b2t: a custom checkstyle rule should work fine.

Comment: As a workaround, if you can mark the output you **do** want somehow, you could wrap the program with something that filters everything but these lines from the output based on a regex or something.

Comment: @Voo Yes, I'd be angry over severe repercussions over minor infractions, especially if it was the first thing you pulled out. I prefer a work environment that assumes I'm a reasonable person, not a mule that needs to be whipped into obedience. A pay cut sounds more like something suitable after repeated deliberate refusal to comply.

Comment: @Inerdial Wait we're talking about a situation where you were already several times reminded that the convention in the package/class was to use the logging methods and not write to sysout directly. I doubt in your company everyone just uses the naming and style conventions he prefers - that must make a great code base. I certainly don't propose such repercussion for first time offenders (although if something like that happened again and again I'd start to wonder why the programmer can't read the documentation and what he's doing working there..)

Comment: @Voo I think the sum of our company's conventions on issues where the choice is arbitrary are: 1. BSD-style braces; 2. Public members are PascalCase; 3. Indent C# with tabs; 4. Don't invent acronyms; 5. Be consistent. This seems to work well enough. (Whether to use logging or write to stdout doesn't fall under this because it changes the behaviour at runtime, and is thus not an arbitrary aesthethic choice.)

Comment: @Inerdial The point is: Making sure there's a consistent code base (and I guarantee you there are more implicit references there you just don't actively think about - MS and sun style guides made sure of that) is worth limiting developers in some points and every style guide should contain at least the "MOST OF ALL: BE CONSISTENT!" clause. That means if a package has a specific logging framework/methodology you don't just go on and use your own just because you like it better. That way lies madness.

Comment: @Voo Of course there are a lot of conventions coming from the .NET ecosystem and the existing code we adhere to automatically. We just don't duplicate them in a company style bible, or enforce crap like whether to put braces around simple `if` statements or not, or private field prefixes. And I believe I've already said I don't consider "logging methodology" as part of what I'm arguing one should be flexible about; you're the one who brought up style guides, which is what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although communicating that developers should not use System.out directly would be preferred, you could set System.out to another PrintStream, then use the alternative PrintStream in the private method.  That way, when people use System.out.println they won't output anything but you'll still be able to use the alternative PrintStream... something like they do here: http://halyph.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-disable-systemout.html

Comment: This is what I'll do. Thanks for the info! (I'll accept this answer as soon as SO lets me)

Answer (score 6):

`public` methods are just that - public. There is no way to restrict access to them.

This kind of problem is usually "solved" by setting up some code-checker like PMD or checkstyle and integrating them into the continuous integration build. So violations of these stuff will be emailed to someone with a big hammer :-)

Comment: Yep some checkstyle rule should be fine. After all that's what static analysis tools are there for.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-commit hooks for your revision control system (SVN, Git, Mercurial) can `grep` for uses of `System.{err,out}` and prevent commit if they occur.

http://stuporglue.org/svn-pre-commit-hook-which-can-syntax-check-all-files/ is an example that takes an action for different changed files based on file extension for SVN.  You should be able to modify that example to take an example based on some subset of Java files and reject if something like the following is true

```
egrep -q '\bSystem\.(err|out)\b'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `System.out` calls to a streams that ignores the output or that redirects it to your logging system.

```
System.setOut(printStream);
```

You can also kill those using `System.out.println` in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to 100% prevent a class from ever using a specific method in Java.

Having that said...

My suggestion would be to add code analysis to your build process and failing the build on any occurrence of `System.out.println`.  A good place to start if you're interested in going this route would be to check out [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).

Also... have some constructive discussions with your developers and talk about why they're doing what they're doing.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `OutputStream` of `System` with your own implementation that would either throw an exception, or redirect the call to your own `print` implementation (which you would need to make public).